# Characterizations of infinite compact Abelian groups and probability spaces based on the forcing notion they give

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, measure-theory, forcing, topological-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite compact Abelian group with the collection $\mathcal{B}$ of Borel subsets of $G$, and $m$ the (unique) normalized Haar measure on $\mathcal{B}$. This gives a natural forcing notion $\mathbb{P}_G$: for $A, B \in \mathcal{B}$ let $A \sim B \iff m(A \bigtriangleup B) = 0$, and let $\mathbb{P}_G$ consists of equivalence classes $[A]_\sim$ where $A \in \mathcal{B}$ and $m(A)>0$, with $[A]_\sim \leq [B]_\sim$  iff $m(A\setminus B)=0.$

Now define an equivalence relation $\equiv$ among infinite compact Abelian groups by

$G \equiv H \iff \mathbb{P}_G$ is forcing equivalent to $\mathbb{P}_H$.

Now my question is the following:

> **Question 1.** What non-trivial facts one can say about $\equiv$ relation$?$

As a sample of explicit question, one may ask the following:

> **Question 2.** Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal and let $\mathfrak{g}_\kappa$ consists of compact abelian groups of size $\kappa.$ What is the cardinality of $\{[G]_\equiv : G \in  \mathfrak{g}_\kappa   \}?$

In general one can ask similar question for probability spaces. Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be an infinite [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) and assign to it, its natural forcing notion $\mathbb{P}_{(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)}$. Also define $\equiv_P$ relation between infinite probability spaces as above.

> **Question 3.** What non-trivial facts one can say about $\equiv_P$ relation$?$

Similar to question 2, one may ask:

> **Question 4.** Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal and let $\mathfrak{p}_\kappa$ consists of probability spaces of size $\kappa.$ What is the cardinality of $\{[G]_\equiv : G \in  \mathfrak{p}_\kappa   \}?$

**Remark.** The equivalence of forcing notions is defined in the comments by Professor Hamkins.

Comment: Forcing-equivalent means that the Boolean algebras (for $G$ and $H$) of Borel subsets modulo measure zero are isomorphic? or something different?

Comment: I found this definition on the web. I asked you because I'm not familiar with the forcing language and I expect it's not necessary to know it to understand your question.

Comment: OK. The set of Borel modulo $\sim$ is already a Boolean algebra, so one can consider its completion. Isn't it just what you're considering? there's a little difference since you're considering the subsets of positive measure, but if I'm correct, removing subsets of measure zero does not matter when passing to the Boolean algebra completion, or I missed something?

Comment: @MohammadGolshani Your proposed definition of forcing equivalence is too strong. Rather, $P$ and $Q$ are forcing equivalent iff there are densely many $p\in P$ for which $\text{RO}(P)\upharpoonright p\cong\text{RO}(Q)\upharpoonright q$ for some condition $q\in \text{RO}(Q)$, and vice versa. For example, every partial order $P$ is forcing equivalent to the lottery sum of a huge number of copies of $P$, but no dense subset of $P$ is isomorphic to a dense subset of even the Boolean completion of that lottery sum. See http://jdh.hamkins.org/common-forcing-extension-via-different-forcing-notions/.

Comment: Another way to say it is: forcing equivalence is a local version of isomorphism in the Boolean completions: below every condition in one forcing notion, there is a cone in the Boolean algebra isomorphic to a cone in the other one.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkinsJ Thanks, I  edited the question and referred to your comment as a definition of equivalence of forcing notions

Comment: An even more simple question would be: Given an infinite compact Abelian group $G$, how far is $\mathbb{P}_G$ from random real forcing?

Comment: @YCor The Haar measure on a compact group can be taken to be a probability measure, so Borel sets modulo ~ is a $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra with the c.c.c., and therefore a complete Boolean algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $G$ is a compact group with infinite weight, then the Maharam type of the Haar measure on $G$ is equal to its weight - See Theorem 2.4 in S. Grekas, On products of topological measure spaces, Handbook of measure theory, Vol. 1, edited by E. Pap, Elsevier 2002.

As the measure algebra of a compact group is Maharam homogeneous, Maharam's theorem implies that it is isomorphic to the usual measure algebra on $2^\kappa$, where $\kappa$ is the Maraham type. This is the usual complete Boolean algebra for adding $\kappa$ random reals.

Therefore: $G \equiv H$
 (in your notation) iff $w(G)=w(H)$.

Comment: What does it say related to the question ?

Comment: It says: $G \equiv H$ (in your notation) iff $w(G) = w(H)$ - Read about [Maharam's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharam%27s_theorem)

Comment: May you explain more.

Comment: @MohammadGolshani This poster is saying that the complete Boolean algebra you get from the measure algebra (i.e. Borel sets modulo nullsets) of $G$ is isomorphic to the measure algebra of $2^{w(G)}$, with its usual coin-flipping measure. This is the complete Boolean algebra for adding $w(G)$ random reals. A good reference for the statements I have just made is Fremlin's Measure Theory, volume 3. The wikipedia article on Maharam's theorem is not so good, I've been meaning to fix it when I have the time.

Comment: In case this is not commonly known, the weight $w(X)$ of a topological space $X$ is the smallest cardinality of a base for the topology.

Comment: @RobertFurber Thanks, may you  present an answer with some details. Possibly you mean Theorem 331L  in Fremlin's book.

Comment: Or may edit the answer given above, to add some details.

Comment: @RobertFurber Is it also true for probability spaces?

Comment: @MohammadGolshani The measure algebras of probability spaces are not necessarily Maharam homogeneous. They are countable products of Maharam homogeneous ones. This is described in Maraham's article, Theorems 1 and 2:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1078424/
Fremlin's version is 332B.

Comment: I don't know enough about forcing to know how products of random real forcings of different cardinals differ from ordinary random real forcing.

Comment: @RobertFurber. It suffices for me. Anyway, the product of random forcing with itself is not just random forcing, it adds Cohen reals.

Comment: @MohammadGolshani Thanks, good to know.

Comment: For the record, the "product" in Maharam's theorem is not the same as the "product" for the theorem that a product of random real forcings adds Cohen reals. The first product is just the product of Boolean algebras, while the second is obtained by taking the product of the posets $A_+ \times A_+$ (where $A_+$ is the poset obtained from the random real algebra by taking away its $0$ element) and forming the completion. Measure algebras never add Cohen reals because they are weakly $\omega$-distributive.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a sampling and analysis of **definable** forcing notions, I would definitely recommend taking a look at the book [Forcing Idealized](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/forcing-idealized/2D68B2180A8AED116895F7728A736AD6) by J. Zapletal; the book is devoted to forcings of the form $Borel(X)/I$ for some (nicely definable) $\sigma$-ideal $I$.
Among other interesting things discussed are different measure algebras; like the ones you described.

Also I'll just add in passing that, it is consistent that the only weakly-distributive c.c.c. forcing notions are Maharam algebras (see for example, [Velick2000](http://www.logique.jussieu.fr/~boban/pdf/splitting.pdf).)

Comment: You know that some people put effort so you can have a nicely formatted citation (including links, stable links) easily in your posts. Right? There is an icon with a chain link inside a comic-style text box. Try it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is that what those things are for? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GVjkg_7bK0

Comment: I don't understand the reference here. Are you comparing me to the Decapodians? Are you comparing yourself to Old Man Waterfall? Because let me tell you right now, a robot's just a garbage can with sparks coming out of it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila that clip was all I could find, I started out looking for a clip of the "garbage can with sparks coming out if it" line, and ended up there. I'm not proud of it but I stand by it.

Comment: Well. If you want to be like the Waterfall family, you might just find your demise in an unexpected way. Maybe you'll be eaten by Lrrr, or murdered by Plutonian penguins, or just the Evil One will do stuff to you. Who knows.

Comment: @AsafKaragila they'll never find me, I'm very careful and keep my identity a secret.

Comment: Not that much, Mr. B.

Comment: Indeed Mr. K. How is Mr. E?